# sumar valores de una columna material-table - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

**tengo una tabla que me muestra los valores que cargo pero necesito que en la misma tabla me sume todos los valores de la columna "valor", no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, si alguien me pudiera colaborar se los agradecería, estoy utilizando material-table de react-js https://material-table.com/#/, necesito que me sume todo lo que hay en la columna "valor" y me la muestre en la misma tabla, he revisado en material-table pero no encontré nada al respecto, si alguien me puede colaborar se los agradecería.**

lo que necesito es que en la tabla me muestre la suma de todos los valores que aparezca en la columna field="valor".

```js
import React, {useContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react';

import { AddBox, ArrowDownward } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

import axios from 'axios';

function Moneda () {
  
  const baseUrlAd="https://miweb.com"
  const [data, setData]=useState([]);

  const peticionGet =async() =>{
   await axios.get(baseUrlAd)
    .then(response=>{
     setData(response.data);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })

  }

   
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
      
    peticionGet();
   
    
  }, 2000);

return () => setInterval(interval);

},[])

      
  const columnas =[
    {
      title:"ID",
      field: "id",
      
    {
      title:'SUELDO BASE ($)',
      field: 'valor',
      format: (field) => field.toLocaleString()
      
     
    },
 
    
  ];

  return (
 
<div id="content" class="app-content">

<div class="panel-body">

<MaterialTable
     
columns={columnas}
data={data}
title= {<><i class="fas fa-calculator fa-2x"></i></> }
backIconButtonText='Página anterior'
pagination
fixedHeader

actions={[

   {
        icon : 'calculate',
        tooltip: 'Calcular',
        onClick: ''
      },
    

]}

options={{
    
    actionsColumnIndex: -1,
 actionsCellStyle: {
 },

 headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#348fe2",  headerStyle: { position: 'sticky'}, boxShadow:"0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255)", color: "white", padding: "0.75rem 0.9375rem", fontSize: 10}
}}
localization={{
    header:{
    actions: 'ACCIONES'
    
  },
  body:{ 
    emptyDataSourceMessage:'No hay registros que mostrar',
    
   },

   
}}



/>




</div>


</div>


  )
}


}

export default Moneda
```

Comment: Oye me gustaría ayudarte pero leer el código cuando no está correctamente formateado desmotiva a las personas que tratan de darte una solución porque hay que hacer un esfuerzo extra por leerlo. Como una humilde recomendación te sugiero que uses un editor de texto moderno y descargues un plugin que te auto-formatee el código. Visual Studio Code es muy bueno y puedes descargar Prettier para que se encargue de formatear tu código.

Comment: listo lo voy a tener en cuenta

Comment: lo que necesito es que en la tabla me muestre la suma de todos los valores que aparezca en la columna  field="valor" eso es todo.